# Complex roots of polynomial $z^3+az^2+bz+c$

Tags: polynomials

Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers where $0\leq c\leq b\leq a\leq 1$.

If $\omega$ is one of the complex roots of polynomial $z^3+az^2+bz+c$ and $|\omega| \geq 1$.

Show that $\omega^4 = 1$.

My work :

$\omega^3+a\omega^2+b\omega+c = 0$

$(\omega-1)(\omega^3+a\omega^2+b\omega+c) = 0$

$\omega^4 + \omega^3(a-1) + \omega^2(b-a) + \omega(c-b) = c$

$|(1-a)\omega^3 + (a-b)\omega^2 + (b-c)\omega + c| = |\omega^4|$

$|(1-a)\omega^3| + |(a-b)\omega^2| + |(b-c)\omega| + |c| \geq |\omega^4|$

As $|\omega| \geq 1$, so

$ |\omega^4| \leq |\omega|^3[(1-a)+(a-b)+(b-c)+c] = |\omega|^3$

Thus $|\omega| \leq 1$ so $|\omega| = 1$

Please suggest how to proceed to get $\omega^4 = 1$.

Comment: Are you sure this works? How about $z^3+z^2+z$ and $w=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$?

Comment: Thank you, Sil. I think this problem statement may be false.